# Spring multiple return type for @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My question is about the capabilities of Spring MVC.

```
@RequestMapping("SOME_VALUE")
RETURN_TYPE NAME_OF_FUNCTION (PARAMS){
     STATEMENTS;
}
```

Is there a way where RETURN_TYPE is dependent on the statements?

For example: When a user clicks on a link, if a certain condition is true, I want the user to download a file (i.e. return a byte[]) but if it's false, I want to show the user a webpage with possible options (i.e. a ModelAndView object).

Now I understand that it can be simply implemented using javascript within the page but coming back to my originial question, is there a way in Spring MVC which does that for us with better handling?

Comment: Just define many `@RequestMapping` handler methods.

Comment: could you give me an example? What I understand is that I could have a little java script code where I would delegate the request to the appropriate mapping. IE for files i'd go to /files/ and for other i'd go to /pages/ ? Is this what you're trying to say?

Comment: Why not just make the return type `Object`?

Comment: Was not aware that it was possible. I'll try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: A method cannot have multiple return types.  That being said there are ways to handle what you describe.  The best approach very much depends on the semantics of the situation. For example if getting the page with options is an error situation then exception handling may be appropriate.  If the web page with options could be seen as a conditional interstitial step in the flow, then I'd use more of a redirect approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring 3.2+ (I'm not sure about previous versions) works as follows. The handler method, `@RequestMapping` annotated, is invoked through reflection regardless of its return type. Spring receives its return value and dispatches a registered [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html) to handle the return value if it supports it.

There are many types of `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`, for `@ResponseBody`, for `ResponseEntity`, for `String`, for `ModelAndView`, etc. You can see most of them in the javadoc.

So one, ugly way, to do this would be to define your method as

```
RequestMapping("SOME_VALUE")
public Object NAME_OF_FUNCTION (PARAMS){
    if (something) {
        return "a string";
    } else if (somethingElse) {
        return new ResponseEntity(new byte[] {1,2,3});
    } else 
        return new OtherType();
}
```

Spring will use the first `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` for which `supportsReturnType` returns `true`.

---

In my opinion, you shouldn't do this. As much as possible, you should make the condition be external, ie come from the request. This way, you could map the condition in the `@RequestMapping` and have multiple `@RequestMapping` methods, one for each possible condition.

Comment: Any reason why you discourage this? I'm trying to learn as much as I can so more details would be more than welcome.

Comment: @ThePlatypus It's not easy code to read and it's not easy code to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning Object you can simply return String and set it to name of your JSP file (i.e. "myjsppage") when you want to return a page, or set it to redirect (i.e. "redirect:/mydownloadablefile") when you want to start downloading. For latter case you will also need to add another controller method with request mapping for "/mydownloadablefile" URL.